# MSC Undefined Error Using Gulp In Visual Studio Code on OSX

Tags: gulp, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to build a C# project using the Visual Studio Code task runner and Gulp on OSX 10.11.4. The [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks) gives an example gulpfile for doing this:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");

var program = "MyApp";
var port = 55555;

gulp.task('default', ['debug']);

gulp.task('build', function() {
    return gulp
        .src('./**/*.cs')
        .pipe(msc(['-fullpaths', '-debug', '-target:exe', '-out:' + program]));
});

gulp.task('debug', ['build'], function(done) {
    return mono.debug({ port: port, program: program}, done);
});
```

When I try to run this code I get an error:

ReferenceError: msc is not defined

The sample code doesn't `require` any msc module but looking through Gulp and its documentation I don't see any `msc` module. Also searching npm finds no `msc` gulp module for compiling C#.

Where would I find this 'msc' module?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that
msc and mono.debug 
might be placeholders.

You can use something like

```
var exec = require('gulp-exec');

gulp.task('build', function () {
  return gulp
    .src('./**/*.vb')
    .pipe(exec('vbnc -optionstrict -warnaserror -debug -target:exe -out:' + program + ' <%= file.path %>'))
    .pipe(exec.reporter());
});
```